# Is it possible in amazon quicksight to refresh data set in 5 minutes or less than 1 hour

Tags: amazon-quicksight

As amazon quicksigt provides auto-refresh for 1 hour 1 week and 1 year, can is it possible to refresh the data set for less than 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

2 options.

You can trigger an ingestion on-demand via the API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/API_CreateIngestion.html) although you may hit limits if you want to do this every 15 minutes.

Alternatively you could use the direct query for your dataset instead of storing in spice, this will increase refresh time for filters, drill downs, etc but the view should always match your datasource.